# group by on associated model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4

I have two models `skills` and `skill_categories` and their association are like

```
skill_categories->hasMany('skills');
skills->belongsTo('SkillCategories', 'joinType' => 'INNER')
```

and `skills` is having an association with `users` where

```
skills->belongsTo('users')
users->hasMany('Skills')
```

I have to select all associated `skills` of the user from `skills` table grouping by `skills.skill_category_id` which will produce result like

```
Skill Category 1
|-- Skill 11
|-- Skill 12
|-- Skill 13
Skill Category 2
|-- Skill 21
|-- Skill 22
```

or like

```
'skill_categories' => [
        'title' => 'Skill Category 1',
        'id' => 1,
        'skills' => [
            0 => [
               'title' => 'Skill 11',
               'id' => 4,
             ],
            1 => [
                'title' => 'Skill 12',
                'id' => 6,
            ]
        ],
]
```

What I'm doing is : **Method 1**

```
$user_skills = $this->Skills->find()
        ->select(['Skills.skill_category_id', 'Skills.title', 'Skills.measure', 'SkillCategories.title', 'Skills.id'])
        ->where(['Skills.user_id' => $user->id, 'Skills.deleted' => false, 'Skills.status' => 0])
        ->contain(['SkillCategories'])
        ->group(['Skills.skill_category_id']);

        foreach($user_skills as $s)debug($s);
```

But this is throwing error as

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'profPlus_db_new.Skills.title' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**Method 2**

```
$user_skills = $this->SkillCategories->find()
        ->where(['Skills.user_id' => $user->id, 'Skills.deleted' => false, 'Skills.status' => 0])
        ->contain(['Skills'])
        ->group(['SkillCategories.id']);

        foreach($user_skills as $s)debug($s);
```

But this gives error as

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Skills.user_id' in 'where clause'

---

**EDIT 2**

***skills schema***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skills` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `skill_category_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `measure` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  )
```

***skill_categories schema***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill_categories` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

***controller code***

```
$user_skills = $this->SkillCategories->find()
   ->contain([
       'Skills' => function($q) use($user) {
           return $q
           ->select(['id', 'skill_category_id', 'title', 'measure', 'user_id', 'deleted', 'status'])
           ->where(['user_id' => $user->id, 'deleted' => false, 'status' => 0]);
    }])
    ->group(['SkillCategories.id']);

    foreach($user_skills as $s)debug($s);
```

***debug output***

```
object(App\Model\Entity\SkillCategory) {

'id' => '581cd4ac-28a7-4016-b535-b34a27d47c0d',
'title' => 'Programming',
'status' => (int) 0,
'deleted' => false,
'skills' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Skill) {

        'id' => '36f16f7f-b484-4fd8-bfc5-4408ce97ff23',
        'skill_category_id' => '581cd4ac-28a7-4016-b535-b34a27d47c0d',
        'title' => 'PHP',
        'measure' => (int) 92,
        'user_id' => '824fbcef-cba8-419e-8215-547bd5d128ad',
        'deleted' => false,
        'status' => (int) 0,
        '[repository]' => 'Skills'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Skill) {

        'id' => '4927e7c1-826a-405d-adbe-e8c084c2b9ef',
        'skill_category_id' => '581cd4ac-28a7-4016-b535-b34a27d47c0d',
        'title' => 'CakePHP',
        'measure' => (int) 90,
        'user_id' => '824fbcef-cba8-419e-8215-547bd5d128ad',
        'deleted' => false,
        'status' => (int) 0,
        '[repository]' => 'Skills'
    }
],
'[repository]' => 'SkillCategories'

}

object(App\Model\Entity\SkillCategory) {

'id' => 'd55a2a95-05a0-410e-9a55-1a1509f76b8c',
'title' => 'Office',
'status' => (int) 0,
'deleted' => false,
'skills' => [],
'[repository]' => 'SkillCategories'

}
```

**Note** : See 2nd object with title **Office** has no `skills` associated with user

Comment: Have you tried to pass the conditions into the contain?
    `$user_skills = $this->SkillCategories->find()->contain(['Skills' = function($q) use($user) {return $q->select(['id', 'user_id', 'deleted', 'status'])->where(['user_id' => $user->id, 'deleted' => false, 'status' => 0]);}])->group(['SkillCategories.id']);`

Comment: Thanks, It did the job. Make an answer of it so that I could mark it as accepted

Comment: I just placed it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the conditions into the contain! :D

```
$user_skills = $this->SkillCategories->find()
    ->contain(['Skills' => function($q) use($user) {
        return $q
        ->select(['id', 'user_id', 'deleted', 'status', 'skill_category_id'])
        ->where(['user_id' => $user->id, 'deleted' => false, 'status' => 0]);
    }])
    ->group(['SkillCategories.id']);
```

Comment: Hey, there is one problem with this script. It is listing all `Skill Categories` even if user has not filled it or is not associated with particular user. Ex. If there are 50 skill categories and user has only skills associated from 10 skill categories, even then it is listing all 50 skill categories where 40 are of no use.

Comment: @AnujTBE are you sure about that? Because I ran this exact query and it works for me.

Comment: yes, I'm sure about that. I have added 2 skill categories from admin panel. Then added 2 skills in one skill category leaving behind 2nd category using demo user panel. When I execute this script, it shows both categories.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include your database schema and your exact code you are running?

Comment: See `Edit 2` in the question